# I got symfony/console errors when installed botman/botman into new laravel app?

Tags: laravel, botman

I try to add botman/botman into my new laravel app, which I created with command :

```
laravel new    LrBtmn
```

But I got error :

```
master@master-at-home:/_wwwroot/lar/LrBtmn$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 9.47.0
master@master-at-home:/_wwwroot/lar/LrBtmn$ composer global require "botman/installer"
Changed current directory to /home/master/.config/composer
Using version ^1.0 for botman/installer
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update botman/installer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- botman/installer[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.3] require symfony/console ~2.3|~3.0 -> found symfony/console[v2.3.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47] but the package is fixed to v6.2.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- botman/installer 1.0.4 requires symfony/console ~2.3|~3.0|~4.0 -> found symfony/console[v2.3.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.49] but the package is fixed to v6.2.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- Root composer.json requires botman/installer ^1.0 -> satisfiable by botman/installer[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.4].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require botman/installer:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require botman/installer:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I tried to add "-W" key :

```
master@master-at-home:/_wwwroot/lar/LrBtmn$ composer global require "botman/installer" -W
Changed current directory to /home/master/.config/composer
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^1.0 for botman/installer
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update botman/installer --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- botman/installer[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.3] require symfony/console ~2.3|~3.0 -> found symfony/console[v2.3.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- botman/installer 1.0.4 requires symfony/console ~2.3|~3.0|~4.0 -> found symfony/console[v2.3.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.49] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires botman/installer ^1.0 -> satisfiable by botman/installer[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.4].

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require botman/installer:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require botman/installer:^2.1" if you know which you need.
```

In composer.json of new project there are no any "symfony/console" packages:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "botman/botman": "^2.7",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Which steps have I to take to run this app?

Thanks!

Comment: try `composer require botman/botman`

Comment: Yes, I run this command with success. But looking at this https://botman.io/2.0/installation docs I need botman/installer, to run commands like "botman new"...  Can I work WITHOUT botman/installer ?

Comment: @mstdmstd you don't need the installer, on the same page of the installation documentation you can just use it directly, go to the bottom of the page :) **Basic Usage without BotMan Studio**

Comment: Thanks! but if there is a way to install BotMan Studio in my project? I many manuals I see BotMan Studio is used...